# Does F# Seq.sort return a copy of the input sequence?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, c#-to-f#

Here is some unexpected (by me) behaviour in F#. I have a simple class that sorts a sequence :

```
type MyQueue<'a when 'a : comparison> ( values : 'a[] )  = 

    let vals =
        Seq.sort values

    member this.First = Seq.nth 0 vals

    override this.ToString() =
        Seq.fold ( fun s a -> s + a.ToString() + ";" ) "" vals
```

I have written a slightly contrived unit test (in C#) to test this:

```
private class TestObject : IComparable
    {
        public TestObject( double Value )
        {
            this.Value = Value;
        }

        public void Update(double NewValue)
        {
            this.Value = NewValue;
        }

        public double Value { get ; private set; }

        public int CompareTo(object Comparable)
        {
            return this.Value.CompareTo( (Comparable as TestObject).Value );
        }

        public override string ToString ()
        {
            return Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestUpdate_OK()
    {

        var nums = new double[]{7,4,3,12,11,3,8};

        var values = nums.Select( n => new TestObject(n) ).ToArray();

        var q = new MyQueue<TestObject>( values );

        Console.WriteLine ( q.ToString() );

        // update one of the values in the collection - should not re-sort the collection
        values[3].Update( 2.0 );

        Console.WriteLine ( q.ToString() );

        Assert.AreEqual( q.First.Value, 3.0 );
    }
```

the Seq.sort does sort the sequence, and the first output is correct :

> 3;3;4;7;8;11;12;

However, updating the test (reference type) object causes the sequence to be re-sorted :

> 2;3;3;4;7;8;11;

I expected that the vals in the MyQueue object would now be unsorted, since the value in the reference object has changed, but the Seq.sort appears to have been performed again. I don't understand, I thought the object of functional programming was to avoid side effects. Why do I get this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this is the statement `let vals = Seq.sort values` is not actually sorting the values until some code consumes the vals variable i.e what your Seq.fold does in toString method, it consumes the vals sequence and at that time the sorting happens and whatever values are there in the values array at that time, those values are sorted, so basically the sorting is happening at the time when you call toString method.

Also, I won't call it FP :) as you are basically doing OOPs by creating type with private state and that state is accessed by type members.

Your problem is related to how sequences works and not in general applicable to FP.

Comment: I think this is the heart of what I don't understand. There are 2 ToString()s in my unit test. I would have expected the sort to occur on the first. Hence the first ToString() is ordered as expected. However, the second output is also re-ordered, and I don't understand where that is coming from.

Comment: And agree it is not FP, but then I don't expcet F# to be purely functional. I did however expect the statement let vals = Seq.sort values to behave functionally

Comment: The sorting is happening when you call ToString, so every time you call ToString, the underlying array is sorted and returned the string representation of this sorted array. In case u make `let vals = Array.sort values` then the sorting will only happen when the object is created and toString will always return the same result, irrespective of modifications to the original array object as Array.sort will create a new sorted array

Comment: Seq are just the F# representation of IEnumerable. If you know LINQ to objects, then the same concepts applies to Seq too. Think of seq as future values, when you do some operation on Seq and the result is a seq that means you are just setting up a pipeline but that pipeline is not executed yet, it gets executed when you start extracting values from it using foreach or toList etc

Comment: Aha, I think I see my confusion. I thought the line let vals =       Seq.sort values was only called once, when the type was created, but it is called every time the ToString is called. Penny has dropped, thanks.

Comment: @Aidan : `let vals = Seq.sort values` *is* only called once. `vals` is a sequence (`IEnumerable<>`), and consequently sorts `values` lazily, not eagerly. If you want an eager sort, use `Array.sort` instead of `Seq.sort`.

Answer (score 1):

> Does F# Seq.sort return a copy of the input sequence?

Yes. What else could it do – to change the order of a set of value types you need to copy (true in all .NET languages).

(This includes LINQ operators in C# and VB: the lazy aspect is that the copy is only made when the first copied element is needed, and at that point a complete new collection is created.)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually check this directly in the sourcecode for f# [here](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/64420#1113981) but in short what it does is call Seq.toArray, sort the array in place and return that array back as the sequence.